# modifying request session in django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

this code is from djagno 2 by example book 
which is very helpful by the way. the question here is how we managed to modify the request session although we didn't modify it except in save method ((( and it's on the session of the cart which in the first line after **init**))) 
what i see is that we have made a copy from the session dictionary at this line
`self.session = request.session`

```
class Cart(object):
def __init__(self, request):
    self.session = request.session
    cart = self.session.get(settings.CART_SESSION_ID)
    if not cart:
        cart = self.session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID] = {}
    self.cart = cart

def add(self, product, quantity=1, update_quantity=False):
    '''
    Add a product to the cart or update it is quantity
    '''
    product_id = product.id
    if not product_id in self.cart:
        self.cart[product_id] = {'quantity': 0,
                                 'price': str(product.price)}

    if update_quantity:
        self.cart[product_id]['quantity'] = quantity
    else:
        self.cart[product_id]['quantity'] += quantity
    self.save()

def save(self):
    self.session['modified'] = True
```

for more clarification you can find the whole code of the project here 
[code](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Django-2-by-Example/blob/master/Chapter07/myshop/cart/cart.py)

i managed to see the user session as I passed it from the context to the template and it's already modified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line does *not* make a copy:

```
self.session = request.session
```

The session in the Cart instance *is* the request session.  self.cart is a dictionary in that session, so all changes to it are written directly to the session.  Then when save is called the modified flag is set.

Comment: i don't mean that is a copy literally, any way my confusion is because we made the session of the cart as an attribute so any change will be done on the cart object itself which doesn't make sense because any change is done on the session of the user, too

Comment: You are still talking as if the cart session and user session are different things.  They both refer to the same object.  I hope that helps.

Comment: oooh, sorry, this is the problem , i didn't realize that when we assign a new variable to another if we made a change to the latter the first will be changed, too     i want to give you a big thank, you helped me a lot